# Form help: input - output for math function

Tags: javascript, function, input, output, logarithm

I need help. I need the javascript code for the following function:

**n = 1 + (log(5156559813)/log(x))/log(3)**

where n is the output and x is the input box.

How do I make the input box be the *x*? Do I use `document.getElementById("x").innerHTML = 1 + (Math.log(5156559813) / Math.log(x)) / Math.log(3)`?

I've searched but the wrong thing keeps coming up *every time*.

Here's my code:

```
<form class="uk-form">

 <fieldset data-uk-margin>

  <input type="text" placeholder="People in your group" id="x">

  <button class="uk-button uk-button-primary">Go!</button>

  <p id="number"></p>

 </fieldset>

 <script type="text/javascript">
  function n(x){
   return document.getElementById("number").innerHTML = 1 + (9.7123600597) / Math.log(x)) / 0.4771212547;
    document.getElementById('x').addEventListener('change', function () {
    document.getElementById('n').innerHTML = n(this.value);
   }, false);
   }
  </script>

 </form>
```

Whenever I hit my button, the page refreshes and I am back at the beginning again.

Thank you very much!

Answer (score 1):

Use `Math.log()` for base e, `Math.log10()` for base 10 and `Math.log2()` for base 2. Note that `log10` and `log2` are currently [not supported](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Math/log) on Internet Explorer

Answer (score 1):

Using [Math.log()](https://developer.mozilla.org/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Objets_globaux/Math/log):

```
function n(x)
{
    return 1 + (Math.log(5156559813) / Math.log(x)) / Math.log(3);
}
```

`x` is your input, and `n(x)` is your output.

If you want this function to be calculated each time that an input's value is changed, you can attach an event listener:

```
// As you stated in the commentes, x can be found in <input id="x">.
document.getElementById('x').addEventListener('change', function () {
    // If your output goes into an <input>
    document.getElementById('n').value = n(this.value);

    // If your output goes into an <div>, <span> or another non self-closing HTML tag:
    document.getElementById('n').innerHTML = n(this.value);
}, false);
```

Comment: Thank you! How would I code my input box to "link" it to the _x_? I'm using _html_.

Comment: @jonahoflosh: You should show your HTML code, I can't guess what you've already done.

Comment: Here's my code so far.....I have no clue how to proceed. `<script type="text/javascript">function n(x)
{
    document.getElementById("number").innerHTML = 1 + (Math.log(5156559813) / Math.log(x)) / Math.log(3);
}
</script>
<center>
 <form class="uk-form">

  <fieldset data-uk-margin>
   <input type="text" placeholder="People in your group" id="x">
   <button class="uk-button uk-button-primary">Go!</button>
  </fieldset>

 </form>
</center>`

Comment: @jonahoflosh: check my answer again then.

Comment: Now, when I hit my button, my page refreshes. I will give my codes in my first question.